# Can't connect to Postgresql via 127.0.0.1

Tags: postgresql, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to a local instance of Postgresql using `127.0.0.1` as IP address but the connection is always denied:

```
⟩ psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -p 5432
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

My `pg_hba.conf` looks like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD 
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     password
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

My `postgresql.conf` has the following entries:

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost, 127.0.0.1'
port=5432
unix_socket_directories = '/private/tmp'
```

I can however connect via the unix socket. What else could be blocking the connection?

Comment: x-posted as https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/183263/7788

Comment: On a unix socket connection run `SHOW port; SHOW listen_addresses;`. Got a software firewall in place that could be filtering connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what happened but a hard reboot of my laptop fixed the issue.